# How to get the get() func to work in tkinter?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, self

```
def Main_Menu():
    for widget in myframe_1.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    PostIt_Count = len([name for name in os.listdir('C:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/tkinterstuff/PostItApp/PostIts')])
    if PostIt_Count > 0:
        for i in range(PostIt_Count):
            PostIt_NamesList = [name for name in os.listdir('C:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/tkinterstuff/PostItApp/PostIts')]
            PostIt_LabelName = 'PostItLabel' + str(i)
            global selected_postit
            selected_postit = tk.StringVar
            PostIt_LabelName = ttk.Radiobutton(myframe_1, text=PostIt_NamesList[i], variable=selected_postit)
            y = ([x for x in range(1, PostIt_Count +1)][i])- 0.4
            y = str(y)[:1] + str(y)[2:]
            yname = '.' + y
            PostIt_LabelName.place(relx=.1, rely=yname)

def Read_PostIt():
    for widget in myframe_3.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    filepath = 'C:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/tkinterstuff/PostItApp/PostIts/'
    postit = selected_postit.get()
    f = filepath + postit
    with open('{}'.format(f), 'r') as fi:
        global text
        text = fi.readlines()
        fi.close()
    text_label = Label(myframe_3, text='{}'.format(text))
    text_label.place(relx=.01, rely=.01)
```

So when I run this I get TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' , why does this happen and how can I fix this. I'm trying to do a Post-It app and I'd like to show the text of the post-it file. I'm calling the Main_Menu function when I start this app and the Read_PostIt function is called when I select a radiobutton of a post-it and click Read -button.

I don't know these kind of stuff very well and I would be veery glad if somebody helped.

Full error traceback:

```py
PS C:\Users\Aatu\Documents\python\pythonleikit> & C:/Python39ni/python.exe c:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/tkinterstuff/PostItApp/post-its.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39ni\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Aatu\Documents\python\pythonleikit\tkinterstuff\PostItApp\post-its.py", line 73, in Read_PostIt
    postit = selected_postit.get()
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error traceback? Also try changing `tk.StringVar` to `tk.StringVar()`

Comment: `PostIt_LabelName = whatever...` is an assignment to the variable literally named `PostIt_LabelName`.  Previously assigning a string to that variable doesn't magically cause this assignment to do something entirely different.  You want to append the labels to a single list, rather than somehow creating new variable names for each one.

Comment: @TheLizzard there's that full traceback

Comment: Hmmm... I changed tk.StringVar to tk.StringVar() and changed the naming system like @jasonharper recommended. Now I'm getting PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:   caused by the line  ``` with open('{}'.format(f), 'r') as fi: ```

Comment: The only problem, as TheLizzard already noted, is the line `selected_postit = tk.StringVar`. It should read:  `selected_postit = tk.StringVar()`. Otherwise, you define the variable as the class of tkStringVar, which does not make any sense.

Comment: Yes, I fixed that and thank ya for help, but that selected_postit.get()  still doesn't return any value. How to fix that? And I can give you the full code if you want.

Comment: it seems to me that You are reassigning the `selected_postit` in the loop every iteration so only the last value will be saved